# Adding `colspan` to html table breaks the structure

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have this table which I designed with HTML. I have not added any bootstrap theme element to this table and it is not fixed width. As you can see below the `td` for customer name has only one span while the description `td` has 4 spans. But the alignment is not what I expected. This is what I try to achieve:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Can any body help me out with this issue? Thanks in advance.

```css
.table-border {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.table-bold-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.table-text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#tripInvoice table tr td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tripInvoice">
  <table class="">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
      <td colspan="3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/129x97" alt="" />
      </td>
      <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right; font-size: 26px; font-weight: 900;">TAX INVOICE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="table-bold-text">Mirissa Water Sports (Pvt) Ltd</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="table-bold-text">"Senasuma", Mirissa - South, Mirissa.</td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">Inv.No:</td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">MWS/15/1545</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="table-bold-text">Contact: +94 77 359 77 32</td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">Date:</td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">2015.05.26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"></td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">Vat No.:</td>
      <td class="table-bold-text">114690244-7000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-bold-text">Customer Name:</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="table-bold-text table-border">Jetwing Travels (Pvt) Ltd</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="table-border table-bold-text" style="border-bottom: none;">46/26, Jetwing House,</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="table-border table-bold-text" style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;">Nawam Mawatha,</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4" class="table-border table-bold-text" style="border-top: none;">Colombo 02</td>
      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background: #d9d9d9; text-align: center;">
      <td colspan="4" class="table-border table-bold-text">DESCRIPTION</td>
      <td class="table-border table-bold-text">QTY (# Pax)</td>
      <td class="table-border table-bold-text">UNIT PRICE</td>
      <td class="table-border table-bold-text">TOTAL</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="table-border">Whales & Dolphin watching on 25th May 2015 Tour No - 2015-5346</td>
      <td class="table-border">12</td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.4,416.18</td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.52,994.16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border">Discount</td>
      <td class="table-border"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border"></td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.52,994.16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border">NBT 2%</td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.1,059.88</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border"></td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.54,054.04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border">VAT 11%</td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.5,945.94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="6" class="table-border">Total Amount</td>
      <td class="table-border">Rs.60,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">All Cheques to be drawn in favour of MIRISSA WATER SPORTS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Account Details:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Mirissa Water Sports (Pvt) Ltd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Acc. No: 213010002896</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Swift Code: HNBSLKLX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Bank Code : 7083</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Hatton National Bank PLC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text">Weligama</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7" class="table-bold-text" style="text-align: center; font-style: italic;">** This is a computer generated document. No signature is required.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxwmoh9f/)

Comment: I prefer you to add colspan attribute to every tag of `<td>`. I see `&nbsp;` rows without colspan. In addition, initially set `<table border="1">` for your reference, then remove it once completing all formatting.

Comment: It's generally recommended to use the Bootstrap CSS (or similar) grid system rather than doing all of your layout with tables.

Comment: @Marc I agree. But this needs to export into excel and I have very good JavaScript for exporting tables into excel so this has to be done with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
<tr>
  <td class="table-bold-text">Customer Name:</td>
  <td colspan="4" class="table-bold-text table-border">Jetwing Travels (Pvt) Ltd</td>
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

In the second `td` you're combining four columns. Instead remove the `colspan` attribute:

```
<tr>
  <td class="table-bold-text">Customer Name:</td>
  <td class="table-bold-text table-border">Jetwing Travels (Pvt) Ltd</td>  
  <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fhsjjkha/1

Here's a clear look at your original layout, so you can see what each table cell is doing:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fhsjjkha/2/

Comment: Thanks. This worked. It would be great if you could explain the background of this. Thanks again.

Comment: As you can see from the second demo, if you remove `colspan="4"` from the 2nd `td`, it might also make sense to adjust the 3rd `td` to `colspan="5"`.

Comment: But then your table layout is wrong, isn't it? He use 7 cols each row, now he has only 4. Some browsers could break the layout. I will try it on work - I think it's an CSS issue. Your solution hasn't in my browser the layout the asker wanted